# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'readlines'

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy, readline

In this Pandas dataframe code:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('data1.csv')
data= np.array(df)
ines = data.readlines()
```

I have met this error:

```
----> 5 lines = f2.readlines()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'readlines'
```

What's wrong?

I just want to be able to read a csv file with this fuction:

```
def file2mat(test_filename, para_num):
    fr = open(test_filename)
    #data= pd.read_csv(test_filename)
    #data= pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u"" +    data.to_csv(header=None,index=False)), header=None)
    #fr= data.values
    lines = fr.readlines()
    print lines
    line_nums = len(lines)
    result_mat = np.zeros((line_nums, para_num))  
    class_label = []
    for i in range(line_nums):
        line = lines[i].strip()
        item_mat = line.split(',')
        result_mat[i, :] = item_mat[: para_num]
        class_label.append(item_mat[-1])  class_label
    fr.close()
    return result_mat, class_label
```

Comment: `readlines` is a method of an opened file.  `data` is an array, though I think there better ways getting an array from a dataframe (`.values` method?)

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do

Comment: `pd.read_csv`, reads and parses the file, creating a `pandas` dataframe.  You can use that as is, or extract a numpy array with dataframe methods.  Assuming the file is properly formed this should be the fastest way of reading csv file.  You just have to understand something about dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

`readlines` is a method of file object but not of numpy array. Follow the pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to see how you can use it. If you want to read the csv file line by line, then there is no use in using pandas. you can stick to `open` method.

```
content = []
with open('data1.csv') as fp:
    content = fp.readlines()
```

This should be enough in your case and now the list `content` has all the lines of your file.